# store empty string as such using spring batch

Tags: spring, tabs, spring-batch, space

I need to read the csv file separated with delimiter and store it to SQL DB. My csv will contains both empty string(" ") and null values(""). Currently all the null values and empty strings are stored as empty string in SQL using spring batch. Now i want to replace null values as null not the empty string.

1|raj|| |N|N|Y|Y

third column is null and fourth one is empty.| is the delimiter.

Comment: Ok. It doesn't look like the 4th one is empty, but that aside, what is the problem? Since you've decided on using sprint batch, I guess you also have attempted something?

Comment: i used custom editor in fieldsetmapper to replace null values and store it as null but both the values third and fourth are getting replace

Answer (score 1):

Using [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html), you could do something like this in your custom FieldSetMapper :

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(yourObject.getField()) && StringUtils.isBlank(yourObject.getField())) {

    yourObject.setField(""); //Empty

} else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(yourObject.getField())) {

    yourObject.setField(null); //Null

}
```

Comment: Its reading the value as either blank or null.only one condition is getting satisfied. what ever condition we checked first getting true.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution may use a custom `FieldSetFactory` injected into current `LineTokenizer`.
In your own `FieldSetFactory.create(...)` set to `null` zero lenght values.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how would one go about achieving this? The argument type of the `mapFieldSet` method is a `FieldSet`. Even if you manage to inject a custom`FieldSet` in your tokenizer, you can't really use it in the `mapFieldSet` method without casting it to your `FeildSet` subclass.